# Совместная работа Go и nginx+apache

Tags: golang, администрирование

Делаю сайт на php (сервер nginx+apache, debian), для сайта нужно сделать api с довольно высокой нагрузкой, поэтому решил освоить Go.
Вопрос: как их связать вместе? Чтобы сайт site.ru обрабатывался апачем, а site.ru/api или api.site.ru - golang???
В администрировании разбираюсь не очень хорошо.

Comment: Вам бы тэги поменять,вопрос скорее по Nginx, чем по Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно это делают так. nginx стает реверс проксей, а go работает как fastcgi или просто webserver. Вот [простой пример](http://mwholt.blogspot.com/2013/05/writing-go-golang-web-app-with-nginx.html). В этой модели апач также находиться за nginx и работает по аналогичной модели.

Плюсы подобного подхода:

- статикой может заниматься nginx (и он делает это хорошо).
- go приложения можно разнести на несколько машин за проксей.
- nginx может быть балансировщиком и раскидывать нагрузку на несколько бекендов.
- nginx может кешировать запросы, существенно снижая нагрузку.

Comment: Все равно немного не понятно. в nginx.conf в разделе "http" добавил запись:
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name site.ru;
   root /var/www/admin/www/site.ru/goserver;
   #gzip off;
   #proxy_buffering off;
   
   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
     }
     
   location ~ /api.* {
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
   }

   try_files $uri $uri.html =404;
 }

(где вместо site.ru мой сайт). 

Перезагрузил nginx и все равно почему то по запросу site.ru/api работает апач.

Comment: А как у Вас все там организовано? может вначале стоит апач, а nginx за ним?
Или может в настройках nginx есть ещё правила, и они перекрывают.

Comment: как бы это узнать... не настолько силен в администрировании

Comment: Вы пишите свой сайт, значит Вы должны знать, как Вы настроили. Или Ваш админ.